# Rails 2.2 - create a new AR::Base class dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I'm using Ruby 1.8.6 and Rails 2.2 for an old app.  I know, I know.

I'm making a plugin called "acts_as_squirrel", which builds another table for the caller class, to store custom data and allow FULL TEXT searching.

The table creation stuff is all working fine, but one of the things I want it to do is to make a new ActiveRecord::Base-inheriting class, called Squirrel.

So, for example, the Resource class calls `acts_as_squirrel("name", "keywords")`.  My acts_as_squirrel code makes (if it doesn't exist) a `squirrel_resources` table, with `id, record_id, name, keywords` columns.  That's all fine.

But, the next thing it needs to do is to define a new ActiveRecord::Base class, to go with this newly created table.  So in this instance, I want to create a `SquirrelResource` class, which goes with the `squirrel_resources` table.

This is what I'm doing at the moment, which doesn't seem to be working:

```
def acts_as_squirrel(options={})
  #create the Squirrel<ClassName> class which goes with this class, eg SquirrelResource to go with Resource.  This is an AR:Base class
  unless defined?("Squirrel#{self.name}")
    eval "
    Squirrel#{self.name} = Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base) do
      extend SquirrelClassMethods
      include SquirrelInstanceMethods
    end
    "
  end
end
```

After doing this, it seems that the SquirrelResource class hasn't been defined.

What's the best way to dynamically add another class in this way, in a way that makes it accessable to the environment, generally, so it's like any other Ar::Base class?

Comment: Wow. I think that plugin should be called "acts_like_a_fox" because that is crazy. That being said is the class not defined or the methods themselves the reason I ask is because I cam into ruby @ 1.9.3 but the docs for 1.8.6 do not seem to suggest passing a block to `Class.new` is an option. Also why use eval?

Comment: this is wrong on so many levels... why are you asking questions on deprecated languages and unsupported frameworks. thats just a waste of everyones time. is it really necessary to use metaprogramming here? is there no way around it?

Comment: Is there any additional functionality needed? If not why not just create a `Squirrel::Base`  that inherits from AR and already has all the required methods then should be simple as `Object.const_set("Squirrel#{self.name}",Class.new(Squirrel::Base))`

Comment: @phoet *"why are you asking questions on deprecated languages and unsupported frameworks"* - because we live in an imperfect world.  *" is it really necessary to use metaprogramming here?"* - Maybe not, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @engineersmnky that could work - what I want really is to be able to say things like `Resource.squirrel_class.find` or `Resource.squirrel_class.create` and have the normal active record methods available.  I don't think i need any additional methods in those 'side' classes.  Maybe that doesn't require me to actually create a new class.  I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: In that case there are easier methods than this. I am away from my computer but if no one answers by tomorrow I will propose a solution

Comment: @engineersmnky ok thanks!  In the meantime I will just do SQL from the "main" classes to get the records (which might be the best thing to do anyway).